# Handling different time zones

Tags: calculations, datetime, comparison

I'm looking for a way to handle date/times with different time zones. For example in [`svn-multi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svn-multi) and [`filemod`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filemod) a date and time with a timezone is returned. I like to be able to compare times in different time zones and convert from one time zone to another one.

The problem here is that different time zones change to [daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_around_the_world) (DST) on different dates. So converting one date from a couple of month back to another time zone would have to take the potential different DST in both time zone *for that date* into account.

I know about the packages like [`datenumber`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datenumber), [`datetime`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) and [`advdate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/advdate), but didn't see a functionality like this. The solution would need to be able to detect the usual time zone strings and map them to the offsets.

Comment: Ugh. If you could talk those tools into reporting timestamps in UTC, life would be infinitely simpler.

Comment: @Harald: I can't influence the timestamps coming in for `svn-multi` because they are generated by an external tool (`svn`, i.e. `subversion`) and depend on the users locale, etc. But I agree with you. My first simple tries all failed because of that complexity.

Comment: Did you try setting TZ=UTC in the environment?

Comment: @Harald: You have misunderstood me. I'm the author of `svn-multi` and would like to add some timezone feature to it. Therefore I do not have any influence to the timezone used by the users.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am afraid you have opened up a can of worms of epic proportions. Read for example http://www.chronos-st.org/Discovering%20the%20Local%20Time%20Zone--Why%20It%27s%20a%20Hard%20Problem.html and weep.

Comment: Does svn really not distinguish between, for example, EST and EDT?

Comment: @TH: It most likely does. I want to be able to convert from one TZ to another one.

Comment: @Martin: So shouldn't it be easy enough to build a mapping from timezone to offset (keeping in mind that some timezones are offsets of only 15 minutes from neighboring ones) from UTC and then do all comparisons in UTC? Granted, this mapping has changed over time, but unless you're planning on keeping all versions of the map, there's little you can do about it.

Comment: @Martin please search for google's closure. It has all the routines, plus good explanations of what gmail uses. (All in JavaScript).

Comment: This is really a locale+SVN problem.  I guess you will get more useful answers if you ask it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Charles: I want to add timezone conversion support to a LaTeX package, not fix any issue with my own locale or SVN settings.

Comment: @Martin: Sure, but the risk is that no-one here will know what the all of the issues are so that a language-agnostic question on SO would get better results.  It sounds like the solution might involve Perl hacking, as well.

Comment: The task is impossible without access to a database of DST switches for different regions, and even then there's no guaratee: I've noticed that one of the most frequent types of updates to Ubuntu updating the time-zone table. So you would have to rely on users keeping that database up-to-date (I have even less of an idea how to do this on Windows). You need finer granularity than time zones. For example, Turkey usually switches to DST on the same day most European countries do, but this year they decided to postpone the switch by 24 hours (tbc)

Comment: (see <http://www.worldbulletin.net/?aType=haber&ArticleID=70872>; only about three weeks of notice!). I think Harald's description of the situation is rather accurate.

Comment: I agree with @TH: to understand what `08:00 MESZ` is we don't need to know when it starts in 2011, we only need to know that it's +0200. Floating time (i.e. "local, you supposedly know what's local to you") is a different matter altogether.

Comment: @Ulrich: Good point. I have the idea to code a mapping table from the timezone strings to the offset and back. Then the user can provide *one* timezone (incl. daylight saving) where all dates are converted to regardless if the timezone would have been used on that date. In other words: If the user selects e.g. Berlin's summer time even the winter dates in the document are displayed in it. One difficult thing, the handling of the numeric date (e.g. special stuff like leap years) seems to be already handled by the `datenumber` package.

Comment: @Martin: For svn-multi, the conversion to the uniform timezone representation can be done outside Latex - the Perl DateTime::TimeZone module comes with an edition of the Olson database.  That way, the Latex need only understand the uniform representation.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the idea! While `svn-multi` provides a Perl script the use is not mandatory, in fact the `autokw` option does the same as the script. I like to avoid to depend on an external script.

Comment: How does SVN report the "time zone"? If it is in +0300, then if it does not adjust that for daylight savings, it is simply giving you garbage output. As alluded to above by Villemoes, there is no such thing as a time zone, only time standards. Such time standards are primarily a construct of local law.

Comment: Looking in .svn/entries for a directory in which I committed files tonight, I see `2011-04-17T00:46:38.861145Z` Given that it isn't yet the 17th for me, that's clearly not local time. Also the Z is a hint.

Comment: @TH.: The `Z` stands for GMT. It might be short for 'Zulu', which is e.g. used by the military to denote GMT datetime. The datetime in `$Id:$` is in the same format, but `$Date$` returns local time.

Comment: @Margin: Yeah, that was the hint. It's almost certainly Zulu. Can you not just read the entries file? It looked like there was code for that already (but I didn't look too closely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be *very* difficult to convert all datetimes into a different timezone with dynamic daylight saving times, i.e. that winter datetimes are displayed without and summer datatimes are displayed with the saving time.

If this feature is dropped and a date is only to be converted from one timezone (where daylight saving might be included) to another then the timezone offsets simply have to be subtracted, i.e. subtract the current timezone offset to get to UTC and then add the target offset. Timezone names like 'UTC', 'CET' (Central European Time) or 'CEST' (Central European Summer Time) can be simple mapped to their offsets using macros. In table with all of these names must be generated. The data should be available online.

Another difficult issue is the handling of the date change if the timezone change went over the day boundary. Then things like days-per-month and leap years have to been taken into account. This is a quite complex thing, but luckily already implemented by the `datenumber` package. However, it seems not particular fast.

Here a proof-of-concept solution which converts one datetime from one timezone to another and calls a macro to typeset it. The `datetime` package is used for the formatting. The code could still be improved, e.g. better macro names. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datenumber}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\getnumtz[2]{%
    \expandafter\@getnumtz\the\numexpr 0#2\relax
        \empty\relax\relax\@nnil{#1}{#2}%
}

\def\@getnumtz#1\relax#2\relax#3\@nnil#4#5{%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
        \edef#4{#1}%
    \else
        \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup
        \expandafter\let\expandafter#4\csname getnumtz@#5\endcsname%
    \fi
}

\newcommand*\definetz[2]{%
    \@namedef{getnumtz@#1}{#2}%
}%

\definetz{Z}{+0000}
\definetz{GMT}{+0000}
\definetz{UTC}{+0000}
\definetz{CET}{+0100}
\definetz{CEST}{+0200}

\newcommand*\converttimezone[9]{%
    % #1 = macro which receives result
    % #2 = year
    % #3 = month
    % #4 = day
    % #5 = hour
    % #6 = minute
    % #7 = second
    % #8 = original timezone
    % #9 = target timezone
    \begingroup
    % Store date:
    \c@myyear=\numexpr#2\relax
    \c@mymonth=\numexpr#3\relax
    \c@myday=\numexpr#4\relax
    \c@myhour=\numexpr#5\relax
    \c@myminute=\numexpr#6\relax
    \c@mysecond=\numexpr#7\relax
    % Get numeric timezones
    \getnumtz\origtz{#8}%
    \getnumtz\targettz{#9}%
    % Calculate resulting hour-minute combination (could be improved)
    \c@myhourminute=\numexpr (#5)*100+(#6) - \origtz + \targettz \relax
    \c@myhour=\numexpr \c@myhourminute / 100\relax% integer devision
    \c@myminute=\numexpr \c@myhourminute - \c@myhour*100\relax
    \loop\ifnum\c@myminute<\z@
        \advance\c@myhour by \m@ne
        \advance\c@myminute by 60\relax
    \repeat
    \loop\ifnum\c@myminute>59\relax
        \advance\c@myhour by \@ne
        \advance\c@myminute by -60\relax
    \repeat
    % Check if the day boundary has been crossed and adjust day:
    \ifnum\c@myhour<0\relax
        \setmydatenumber{mydatenumber}{\value{myyear}}{\value{mymonth}}{\value{myday}}%
        \advance\c@mydatenumber by \m@ne
        \setmydatebynumber{\value{mydatenumber}}{myyear}{mymonth}{myday}%
        \advance\c@myhour by 24\relax
    \else\ifnum\c@myhour>23\relax
        \setmydatenumber{mydatenumber}{\value{myyear}}{\value{mymonth}}{\value{myday}}%
        \advance\c@mydatenumber by \@ne
        \setmydatebynumber{\value{mydatenumber}}{myyear}{mymonth}{myday}%
        \advance\c@myhour by -24\relax
    \fi\fi
    \edef\@tempa{\unexpanded{#1}{\themyyear}{\themymonth}{\themyday}{\themyhour}{\themyminute}{\themysecond}{#9}}%
    \expandafter
    \endgroup\@tempa
}
\newcounter{myhourminute}
\newcounter{myyear}
\newcounter{mymonth}
\newcounter{myday}
\newcounter{myhour}
\newcounter{myminute}
\newcounter{mysecond}
\newcounter{mydatenumber}
\makeatother


\usepackage{datetime}
\newcommand\myshowdate[7]{\formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1} \formattime{#4}{#5}{#6} #7}

\begin{document}

\converttimezone\myshowdate{2011}{04}{18}{12}{16}{55}{CEST}{UTC}

\converttimezone\myshowdate{2011}{04}{18}{23}{16}{55}{UTC}{CEST}

\converttimezone\myshowdate{2011}{04}{18}{01}{16}{55}{CEST}{UTC}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following correct output:

> Monday 18th April, 2011 10:16 UTC
>    Tuesday 19th April, 2011 01:16 CEST
>    Sunday 17th April, 2011 23:16 UTC

So the day boundary is handled correctly. I didn't tested leap-days yet, but I trust `datenumber` to do this correctly.

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer now to conclude the question. This seems the only reasonable way for me so far. If anyone comes up with something better I'm happy to accept that answer.

Comment: Is it possible to give input in the line -
"\converttimezone\myshowdate{2011}{04}{18}{12}{16}{55}{CEST}{UTC}"
as '\today' instead of your specified format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This gets complicated very quickly so I'm just going to put a starting point.

http://cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/tz-link.htm

That link should contain enough information to get you started.  Time zones are complicated and always changing, most unix systems use the database found above to use time zones properly.  Related libraries and documentation can be found above.