# Tag \today in different countries

Tags: datetime

I would like to know if it is possible to specify another country than my home country as the reference for the tag `\today`. I need to submit works in a different time zone so when I submit it, sometimes the day isn't right any more in this specific country since the reference for the tag `\today` is another time zone's country.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/handling-different-time-zones

Comment: `datetime2-calc` provides a way to convert to UTC+00:00, which is a starting point.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you want. By this I mean same input and sample output.

Answer (score 3):

I think that I misunderstood your question as at first I thougtht that you wanted to be able to switch the language that is used by the `\today` command. Inspired partly by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450950/how-do-i-get-today-to-display-todays-date-as-14-sep-2018/450973#450973), if this is what you want then you can do this using the [datetime2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage[showdow,useregional]{datetime2}
\begin{document}

    \selectlanguage{french} \today

    \selectlanguage{british} \today

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Rereading your question, it seems that, instead, you want to change the actual time that is used this looks a little trickier...

Comment: @marmot Yes, I agree -- see my last comment:) Was planning to come back and answer the real question when I finish doing what I am supposed to be doing now...